# Capacitive touch sensor senses every materials touch

Tags: arduino, sensor, capacitive

I have a ttp223 capacitive touch sensor. It has three pins, VCC GND and I/O. I left I/O open for test purposes. I connected the VCC to 5V and GND to ground. When I touch the sensor, its led indicator lights up, sensor works fine. I wanted to see if it works through wood because I want to make a touch sensitive wooden surface controlled by arduino. When I brought the wood closer, without even touching the corresponding area with my finger on the wood, sensor lights up.I tried touching the sensor with various materials including plastic and it still lights up. It detects every touch from every material. Obviously I dont want this. How can I solve this?

Comment: Perhaps changing the sensitivity capacitor described in the datasheet might help (experimentally) https://files.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove-Touch_Sensor/res/TTP223.pdf

Comment: @vicatcu I dont thinks thats the problem. Sensor triggers with non human contact which makes no sense. Could it be because my hand is near?

Comment: I changed the sensitivity, now it doesnt work at all. I have trouble reading the value of smd capacitors

Comment: if you are holding the thing it is effectively an extension of you as an  AC path to ground

Comment: I do actually, but when I touch the screen of my phone with the same materials it doesnt work. I thought the sensor works like my phones screen, how is it different?

Comment: sensitivity... everything looks like a capacitor at some resolution of approximation

Comment: I soldered some little caps I desoldered from old laptop motherboards. I dont know if I soldered one with a reasonable value because they dont have capacitance text on them. After that the sensor completely stopped working which made me think that the caps were too high. I saw a video on youtube with this sensor without any extra cap touching a piece of wood and works fine.

Comment: no cap is maximum sensitivity according to datasheet... 50pF is max value that should be used

Comment: I said the cap value was too high, not the sensitivity. I soldered a very high value cap thus the sensor stopped working.